# Using same function to process two different List Types

Tags: java, class, oop

I have two classes

```
class A {
    String name,
    String value

    public A(name, value) {
        this.name = name,
        this.value = value
    }
}

class B {
    String name,
    String value

    public B(name, value) {
        this.name = name,
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

I want to do something like below

```
List<?> mylist = condition?List<A> list:List<B> list;

print(mylist.get(0).name)
```

Based on a condition, I want to assign the object to a list. I want a single method to process the List and not two separate functions to process two lists of different types.

How do achieve this in java?

Comment: Using conventional indenting will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Don’t create multiple classes for exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

## Define an interface

We can more briefly declare your two example classes as [records](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record A ( String name , String color ) {}
record B ( String name , String place ) {}
```

In a record, the compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` and `hashCode`, and `toString`. The getters are the name of the member field itself, with no `get…` prefix.

To be able to access the coincidentally named `name` member field from either type, we could define and implement an interface. That interface would define a single method.

```
interface HasName { String name() ; }
```

We change the declarations of our two records to  mark them as implementing that interface.

```
record A ( String name , String color ) implements HasName {}
record B ( String name , String place ) implements HasName {}
```

Now remember that the compiler is implicitly creating our getter methods. As records, both `A` & `B` have a method named `name`, even though we do not see it here. That implicit `name` method fulfills the contract requirements of the `HasName` interface.

Make our lists.

```
List< A > listA = … ;
List< B > listB = … ;
```

Now we can select between either.

```
List< ? extends HasName > list = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? listA : listB ;
```

By the way, as of Java 16, we can do all this locally. Interfaces, records, and enums can all be defined locally.

Some example code.

```java
interface HasName { String name ( );}

record A ( String name , String color ) implements HasName { }
record B ( String name , String place ) implements HasName { }

List < A > listA = List.of( new A ( "Alice" , "purple" ) );
List < B > listB = List.of( new B ( "Bob" , "Tukwila" ) );

List < ? extends HasName > list = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? listA : listB;

System.out.println( "list.get(0).name() = " + list.get( 0 ).name() );
```

> list.get(0).name() = Bob

You could just as well use conventional classes here. Records were used for their brevity. However you do it, just match up the getter method names to the interface method name.